# Issue with counting rows using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to execute my MYSQLi statement that's supposed to count rows. I don't get an error when I do a query but when I try and echo the result, it just breaks the html lines below the echo.

Here is my code:

```
$db = doDB();
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) From `Keys`";
$stmt = $db->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
```

doDB() Function:

```
function doDB() {
 $dbHost = 'localhost';
 $dbName = '';
 $dbUser = '';
 $dbPass = '';

 $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
 return $db;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long discussion you can get count like that:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) From `Keys`");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];
```

Note that this credit goes to **@deceze**.

Comment: Some error handling would be nice, but yeah....

Comment: This works. Thank you. Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: @stat.us: also say thanks to deceze who suggest u to show your connection function. :)